# Expected number of rounds to get particular groupings when rolling a die

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

My problem is similar to the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087183/expected-number-of-rounds-to-get-a-particular-sequence-on-a-die) but with one minor modification:

Given a fair die, what is the expected number of rolls to get all even numbered sides first then all odd numbered sides?

- **Example 1** The sequence of rolls: $2,4,6,1,3,5$ is of length 20
- **Example 2** The sequence of rolls: $1,\left\{4\right\},3,\left\{2\right\},5,\left\{6\right\},\left\{1\right\},2,\left\{3\right\},4,\left\{5\right\}$ is of length 11

I came up with the following

$$E(T) = E(T_{even}) +  E(T_{odd})$$
$$E(T_{even}) = E(T_{odd})$$
$$E(T_{even}) = 6(\frac{3}{6} + \frac{2}{6} + \frac{1}{6})$$

$$E(T) = 2E(T_{even})$$
$$E(T) = 12$$

However running a simulation, I obtain a result that $E(T) \approx 22$

Given the difference, I'm not sure which is correct, simulation seems to give a more reasonable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have probability $p$ of an event occuring, the expected time for it to occur for independent trials is $1/p.$

The expected time to get all even sides is the time to get the first even side (the probability of rolling any even is 1/2, so time is 2) + the time to get the second even side (now have probability 2/6 to roll one of the two remaining evens, so time is 3) + the time to get the third (now have prob 1/6 to roll the last so expected time is 6). To the total expected time is 6+3+2 = 11. You're right that it will be the same for the odd sides, so the answer is 11+11 = 22.